# facebook comment box for iframe application

Tags: facebook

I have created an iframe facebook application.  I want to use the facebook's comments functionality in this app. A user should be able to comment from my facebook applcation to facebook. It should be posted to wall also.

I have tried to implement through fb:comment tag but the issue is that sometimes it is not rendered and when it is rendered then the comment is not posted at all (it shows the database error).

Please tell me (any links would be helpful) how to do it and if it is possible..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found the solution..,,

`<fb:comments xid="titans_comments" >
</fb:comments>`

the comments tag should have a "xid" attribute and it will then post the comments...

Hope this will help anyone who visits this post.